# UILabel in UITableViewCell is not being shown

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableViewController with three labels. The first two are from the `.textLabel` and `.detailTextLabel`, I have added a third label into the storyboard and hooked it up to a `UITableViewCell` file. When I run, the app crashes unless the label is  set as an optional with a "?", but nothing is still presented in the table. If it does not have the optional sign, it crashes and I get a response saying *"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"*. The other two `.textLabel` and `.detailTextLabel` work fine. I would appreciate any help!

Here is my `TableViewController` File,

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.groupscores.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifier) as? ScoresPageCell
    if (cell != nil) {
        cell = ScoresPageCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellidentifier)
    }
    let groupscorelist: PFObject = self.groupscores.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
    var scores: AnyObject = groupscorelist.objectForKey("Score")!
    var user: AnyObject = groupscorelist.objectForKey("User")!
     var info: AnyObject = groupscorelist.objectForKey("Info")! 
    cell!.textLabel?.text = "\(scores)"
     cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(user)"
    cell!.UserNameCellLabel?.text = "\(info)"


    return cell!

}
```

And my UITableViewCell File,

```
class ScoresPageCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var UserNameCellLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

}
```

Comment: There's a pretty glaring bug here: `if (cell != nil) {
        cell = ScoresPageCell...`

Comment: I agree with @NRitH and also if you are using a custom cell, implement the two other labels into the custom  cell class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this my friend:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ScoresPageCell


    let groupscorelist = self.groupscores[indexPath.row]

    var scores = groupscorelist["Score"] as! String  // cast it to String if they are string.
    var user = groupscorelist["User"] as! String
    var info = groupscorelist["Info"] as! String

    cell!.text1?.text = scores
    cell?.text2?.text = user
    cell!.UserNameCellLabel?.text = info
    return cell
}

class ScoresPageCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var text1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var text2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet  weak var UserNameCellLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: Overall, this looks good. I'd make some changes, though: for `cell!.text1?.text = "\(scores)"`, you can simply assign the raw `String` to the text (`cell!.text1?.text = scores`); there's no need to wrap it in a string format specifier; and I'd declare the three outlets as `weak`, per Apple's guidelines.